# Error build VSTS - VSTest task - OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL

Tags: selenium, build, azure-devops, specflow, iedriverserver

In my build the following error is occurring:

```
[error]Error Message:
[error]   Test method PROJECTXPTO.FeatureBDD.NameFeature.NameTestCase_Variant0 threw exception: 
[error]OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:1337/session/805876aa-c332-4de7-a8a2-3fb0d5bb00c2/url timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
[error]Stack Trace:
[error]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[error]   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
[error]--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[error]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
[error]   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[error]   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[error]   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
[error]   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
[error]   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
[error]   at Client.Serc.UI.Test.Configurations.Main.TestInit() in D:\a\1\s\Automation\PROJECTXPTO\PROJECTXPTO\Configuration\Main.Main.Base.UI.cs:line 47
[error]   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
[error]   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
[error]   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
[error]   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
[error]   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
[error]   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
[error]   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
[error]   at PROJECTXPTO.FeatureBDD.NameFeature.ScenarioSetup(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
[error]   at PROJECTXPTO.FeatureBDD.NameFeature.ValidacoesDeUsuarioESenhaNaTelaDeLogin(String usuario, String senha, String mensagem, String[] exampleTags) in D:\a\1\s\Automation\PROJECTXPTO\PROJECTXPTO\Feature BDD\SPEC.Login.UI.feature:line 9
[error]   at PROJECTXPTO.FeatureBDD.NameFeature.NameTestCase_Variant0() in D:\a\1\s\Automation\PROJECTXPTO\PROJECTXPTO\Feature BDD\SPEC.Login.UI.feature:line 9
```

I use specflow 2.3.2, selenium 3.13.1, IEDriverServer 3.9.0.

The build is performed by the VSTS host agent (Agent queue: Hosted VS2017).

I tried to find some solution on the site, but none worked for me.
Would anyone have any tips?

Comment: I tried to update IEDriver to 3.14, but it still has the same error

Comment: As you are using `selenium 3.13.1` try to use `IEDriver 3.13.1`

Comment: Can you share the detailed logs?

Comment: Worked using IEDriver 3.13.1

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to talk to localhost according to the log: “http://localhost:1337”. How do you start that website there?